# Understanding items size limit in dynamoDB

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I'm trying to understand the items size limit in dynamo DB, but I'm not sure of what an item actually is.

Looking at the image below, does the 400kb limit apply to the red rectangle (Primary key/Sort key) or to the green rectangle (only primary key)?

Sorry if the question is stupid but I can't find a definitive answer by myself.

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3qsDN.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your terminology on the diagram is wrong, which is probably how you're confused.

When people say PK that's the Partition Key, and SK is the Sort Key. Together they make the Primary Key, which is the unique identifier for an item. The SK is actually optional, in which case the Partition Key is also the Primary Key.

An Item is the data put by PutItem and retrieved by GetItem. Basically, a row.

An Item Collection is all items sharing the same PK value.

Comment: Much clearer.. Thank you!

Comment: Cool. Feel free to accept the answer.